# Asynchronously processing the attached files in an email (Spring Mail Integration)

Tags: android, spring, email, android-asynctask, spring-integration

If I have a Spring app with a mail server inbound channel, what is the best way to process every file in every email (I poll approx. every 1 min, and fetch 1 email with multiple attachments).

Although I can apply multithreading at the receiving channel (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor or ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) this doesn't help much because if I have 10 files attached in an email, their processing is pretty much bound to one thread.

I've been keeping this pretty synchronous until now, because I wanted to aggregate some data for every email, and send a response after all files have been processed. I believe this could also be done in a better way.

In general how can I asynchronously process every file in every email, and then again asynchronously build an email reply?

Comment: I thought that the title was clear enough, but anyway, I added the same thing in a question format :)

Comment: A sentence that forms a question should end with an `?` -- but now I (and hopfully very one else) understand what you are asking for.

Comment: yeah, sorry, really. I am kinda under stress today

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are asking for [`java.util.concurrent.Future`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). This is a java core concept to block until a (method) result is calculated. (see [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for an example)

The Spring [`@Async`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) support the `Future` concept too.

So the only think you need to do is having a method that uses `@Async` takes one attachment of the Mail as argument and returns what ever is calculated in a future.
The you need to invoke all this methods for all attachments (asynchronous) and store the immediately returned future in a list. After all methods are invoked. You try to get the feature results in an new loop. After this loop is finish all attachments are proceed asynchronous.

```
 processOneMail(List<Attachement> attachments) {
      List<Future<AttachmentResult>> futures = new ArrayList...

      for(Attachment attachment : attachments) {
        futures.add(processOneAttachment(attachment)); //async
      }

      List<AttachmentResult> attachmentResults = new ArrayList...
      for(Future<AttachmentResult>> future : futures) {
         attachmentResults.add(future.get()); //eventually blocks
      }
      //now all attachments are calculated and stored in the list.      
      ...
    }
@Async
Future<AttachmentResult> processOneAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
   ...
}
```

See also: http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/08/spring-asynchronous-support/